# Could not load file or assembly 'Jedox.Palo.Comm.DLL' or one of its dependencies in ASP.NET Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dll, reference

Ok so I am trying to use the Palo DotNet SDK to access the OLAP server.

First I created an empty c# project, added the reference to Jedox.Palo.Dll.
It seems Jedox.Palo.Dll uses two other dll's namely 1. libpalo_en.dll 2. libpalo2.dll 
(which are not type libraries themselves so can't be added as a references. See error below for more details on that). 
So I read somewhere on SO that I need to add them to the Debug/bin directory of my application, and on doing so still got the error in the title. Then I changed the target framework from 4.0 to 2.0 and viola it worked!

So I then set out to do the same for a ASP.Net Website
I added the reference for the Jedox.Palo.Comm.dll and added the two other files to the bin directory. Image here: http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/6835/paloerror.png
But then I get the error message again. I have done everything I did in the C# application - Add the dll's to the bin dir, change the target framework to 2.0.

Here is the detailed error:
Warning 1   C:\Users\Development\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\TestPalo\Default.aspx: ASP.NET runtime error: Could not load file or assembly 'Jedox.Palo.Comm.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found. C:\Users\Development\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\TestPalo\Default.aspx    1   1   C:...\TestPalo\

Here is the error message (pop up) if I try to add libpalo_ng.dll or libpalo2.dll as a reference:
A reference to 'C:\Users\Development\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\TestPalo\Bin\libpalo_ng.dll' could not be added. No type libraries were found in the component.

So how can I overcome this. And if you're suggesting Reflector, it doesn't even tell me that Jedox.Palo.Comm.dll uses the other two dll's. So I'm not certain of its efficacy.

And is there like a separate folder where those two dll's need to be put, since this is an asp.net webite, since I feel that if it worked as a C# Application, there is no reason not to work as a web app.
Also should I add any references to those other two dll's int the web.config file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this error happening in the VS web server or on IIS?

Comment: VS Web Server. So I was wondering if it is necessary to add the two dll that Jedox.Palo.Comm.Dll uses to the web.config file?

Comment: It should be enough to put them in your project's bin folder... You could try adding them in the web.config file in the assemblies section but I don't think it'll do anything... Have you tried a full clean/rebuild of the project?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple times. And I am not sure of the syntax to add the assemblies in web.config. Can you help me out with that?

Comment: Sure, this article shows you what you want: http://weblogs.asp.net/chrismoseley/archive/2008/10/28/shared-assemblies-without-the-gac.aspx you don't need to follow his junction point instructions, just the first bit of xml that's highlighted.

Comment: Solved. Just added the two depended dll to the sysWOW64 folder. Nothing else worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Just added the two depended dll to the sysWOW64 folder. Nothing else worked!

Answer (score 0):

When running .net site, enable 32 bit Application in the IIS app pool configuration. Palo requires 32 bit.